# How to update a datagridview with updated sql table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a WinForms App and I fill it with a table from a database (local database, table is called '`table`'). When I update the table within the C# code the changes takes effect in the Database but are not shown in the DataGridView.

How can I update the DGV? I've found `dataGridViewStock.Refresh();` and `dataGridViewStock.Update();` but none of these two worked.

Anybody has a tip for me?

Comment: How do u bind the datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating your datatable in c# you may simply write

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource=null;
yourDataGridView.DataSource=dt;
```